# Grant role to new_user is not working in 12C

Tags: oracle12c, role

```
DBA_USER: create role test_2

DBA_user: grant create session, create any table, create any procedure to test_2;

grant succeeded.....

grant test_2 to new_user
```

now new_user:

```
create table items (item_number number(3) primary key, 
                    item_name varchar2(40), 
                    item_desp varchar2(20), 
                    item_qty number(3));

Error: you have insufficient privilege
```

Comment: Do you have particular Oracle error code? Which operating system?

Comment: window server 2008, installed 12 c on it

Comment: Please see recommendations below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exact Oracle error code would help, but first guess would be that `new_user` does not have privilege on `SYSTEM` (or other `tablespace`). It is not recommended to use SYSTEM tablespace in general, so let's create tablespace first.

Create separate tablespace for user :

```
   create tablespace tbs_for_new_user
   datafile 'tbs_nu.dbf' size 50m;
```

Then assign newly created tablespace to user as default

```
   alter user "NEW_USER"
   default tablespace "TBS_FOR_NEW_USER"
   temporaty tablespace "TEMP"
   account unlock; // if you did not unlock new_user account yet

   alter user "NEW_USER" quota 50000m on TBS_FOR_NEW_USER;
   alter user "NEW_USER" DEFAULT ROLE "TEST_2";
```

Then try to create table.